# Struts 2 Avoid duplicate action

Tags: java, configuration, struts2, annotations, struts-validation

Consider below sample in a struts 2 application. This is a page which shows a grid and user can export SAME grid to PDF.

We develop a class with two actions, one action returns a grid as JSON and the other one export the SAME grid to PDF.

The structure of code is as below:

Two different action maps has been defined `/ShowGrid` and `/ExportGrid`

```
@Action (name="ShowGrid") // Result will be set to JSON
@validation ( @Required (..... // Validation Rules for fromDate toDate etc
public String showGrid(){
gird = serviceFacade.getGrid(fromDate,toDate);
return SUCCESS;
}


@Action (name="ExportGrid" ) //Result will be set as stream
@validation ( @Required ..... // Validation Rules for fromDate toDate etc
public String exportGrid(){
grid = serviceFacade.getGrid(fromDate,toDate);
inputStream = convertGridToStream(grid); // By using jasper report or other tools
return SUCCESS;
}
```

As you can see the above methods has lots of common structure,

- The validation is duplicated ( In my use case the validation rules are LOT)
- Calling the service method is duplicated

Is there any way to avoid this ?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can map many actions to the same method, using `@Actions` annotation. Inside the actions method you can get the name from the action context and define the logic.

```
@Actions({
  @Action ("ExportGrid"), //Result will be set as stream
  @Action ("ShowGrid") // Result will be set to JSON
})
@validation ( @Required ..... // Validation Rules for fromDate toDate etc
public String doGrid(){
  grid = serviceFacade.getGrid(fromDate,toDate);
  if (ActionContext.getContext().getName().equals("ExportGrid")
    inputStream = convertGridToStream(grid); // By using jasper report or other tools
  return SUCCESS;
}
```